# Returning a sorted array of objects in java with only SINGLE loop

Tags: java, arrays

**No Arraylist or Comparator is allowed.**.   **Only one loop is allowed.**   Im confused about how to return 'F' immediately after 'M'. Could smb help with this? How can I return 'M' of a person followed by immediately his 'F' of the same person withing only **SINGLE** loop.  The method returns an array which starts with 'M'(midterm) of the first person (object) followed immediately by his 'F' (final). Let's say.. intially it looks like this:

```
| Index | First  | Last      | ID | ExamType | Score |    
    |-------+--------+-----------+----+----------+-------|    
    |     0 | Linus  | Torvalds  |  9 | final    |    91 |    
    |     1 | Brian  | Kernighan |  6 | midterm  |    90 |    
    |     2 | Donald | Knuth     |  3 | midterm  |   100 |    
    |     3 | Grace  | Hopper    |  0 | final    |    80 |    
    |     4 | James  | Gosling   |  5 | final    |    90 |    
    |     5 | James  | Gosling   |  5 | midterm  |   100 |    
    |     6 | Brian  | Kernighan |  6 | final    |    80 |    
    |     7 | Dennis | Ritchie   |  4 | final    |    80 |    
    |     8 | Dennis | Ritchie   |  4 | midterm  |    90 |    
    |     9 | Grace  | Hopper    |  0 | midterm  |   100 |    
    |    10 | Donald | Knuth     |  3 | final    |    90 |    
    |    11 | Linus  | Torvalds  |  9 | midterm  |    90 |
```

The final product of the method should be this:

```
| Index | First  | Last      | ID | ExamType | Score |    
    |-------+--------+-----------+----+----------+-------|    
    |     0 | Brian  | Kernighan |  6 | midterm  |    90 |    
    |     1 | Brian  | Kernighan |  6 | final    |    80 |    
    |     2 | Donald | Knuth     |  3 | midterm  |   100 |    
    |     3 | Donald | Knuth     |  3 | final    |    90 |    
    |     4 | James  | Gosling   |  5 | midterm  |   100 |    
    |     5 | James  | Gosling   |  5 | final    |    90 |    
    |     6 | Dennis | Ritchie   |  4 | midterm  |    90 |    
    |     7 | Dennis | Ritchie   |  4 | final    |    80 |    
    |     8 | Grace  | Hopper    |  0 | midterm  |   100 |    
    |     9 | Grace  | Hopper    |  0 | final    |    80 |    
    |    10 | Linus  | Torvalds  |  9 | midterm  |    90 |    
    |    11 | Linus  | Torvalds  |  9 | final    |    91 |
```

my code:

```
 public static Exam[] collateExams(Exam[] exams)
        {
            Exam [] r = new Exam[10];
            r = exams;
            int[] position = new int[10];
            int index = 0;


            for(int i = 0; i < exams.length; i++)
            {
                if(r[i].getExamType() == 'M')
                {   

                    r[index*2] = new Exam(r[index].getFirstName(), r[index].getLastName(),
                                      r[index].getID(), r[index].getExamType(), r[index].getScore());

                    position[index*2] = r[index].getID();
                    index++;

                    if((r[index+1].getExamType() == 'F') && (position[index+1] == r[i].getID()))
                    {
                        r[index+1] = new Exam(r[index].getFirstName(), r[index].getLastName(),
                                  r[index].getID(), r[index].getExamType(), r[index].getScore());
                    }
                    /*if(position[i].getID() == r[i].getID())
                        r[i] = new Exam(r[i].getFirstName(), r[i].getLastName(),
                                  r[i].getID(), r[i].getExamType(), r[i].getScore()); 
                        */


                }

            }

            return r;
        }
```

Comment: This looks likes homework. What's the criteria of the sort function?

Comment: 'M' of the person should be followed by his 'F' immediately

Comment: "`Only one loop is allowed`", but can you loop more than once?

Comment: yes, but only a single iteration construct such as one for or one while loop @iRuth

Answer (score 0):

Your task is to return a sorted `Exam` array from the input given and you are meant to sort by exam type. Basically, you would need to loop through the `exams` array the first time and save every entry that has midterm exam type. While doing this, also save the expected final index for the person. Then, you would loop through the `exams` array a second time, saving every entry that has final exam type, using the indices saved in the `HashMap`.  I did not test the code, but I commented it, so you should understand it.

```
public static Exam[] collateExams(Exam[] exams){
    Exam [] r = new Exam[exams.length];
    // used to keep track of the person's ID and the index in the return array
    Map<Integer, Integer> finalIndices = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    int midtermIndex = 0;

    // first loop, saves only midterm
    for(int i = 0; i < exams.length; i++) {

      // midterm comes first, so its index in the array is always even 
      // final comes after midterm, so its index is always odd

      if(exams[i].getExamType() == 'M') {
        // midterm found, save in r
        r[midtermIndex] = new Exam(exams[i].getFirstName(), exams[i].getLastName(),
                              exams[i].getID(), exams[i].getExamType(), exams[i].getScore());
        // save the final index position for this person (midtermIndex + 1)
        finalIndices.put(exams[i].getID(), midtermIndex+1);
        // increment by 2, 
        midtermIndex+=2;
      }
    }

    //second loop, saves final
    for(int i = 0; i < exams.length; i++) {
      if(exams[i].getExamType() == 'F') {
        // final found, get the index from hashmap and save in r
        int finalIndex = finalIndices.get(exams[i].getID());

        r[finalIndex] = new Exam(exams[i].getFirstName(), exams[i].getLastName(),
                            exams[i].getID(), exams[i].getExamType(), exams[i].getScore());
      }
    }

    // should be sorted
    return r;
}
```

Good luck and let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I can do with two loops too. But the specs indicate only a SINGLE loop.

Comment: Great! That's why it's homework and you need to figure it out ;).